# How to use multiplate onkeyup input?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have this input, I want use 2 onkeyup in one input, How use it?

I want sepret my number 3 number with comma and I want my input value of a factor of 10 too.

For example, if the user enters the number 100214, the user will immediately see the number 10021 (No decimal) in span result and see the number 100,214 in input.

```js
function separateNum(value, input) {

    var nStr = value + '';
    nStr = nStr.replace(/\,/g, "");
    x = nStr.split('.');
    x1 = x[0];
    x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while (rgx.test(x1)) {
        x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
    }
    if (input !== undefined) {

        input.value = x1 + x2;
    } else {
        return x1 + x2;
    }
}

function onInputChange(e) {
    const span = document.getElementById('result');
    span.innerHTML = Math.floor(e.value / 10);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeyup="onInputChange(this); separateNum(this.value,this);">
<span id='result'>please enter number</span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function test2(value, input) {

    var nStr = value + '';
    nStr = nStr.replace(/\,/g, "");
    x = nStr.split('.');
    x1 = x[0];
    
    x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while (rgx.test(x1)) {
      x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
     console.log(x1)
    }
    if (input !== undefined) {

        input.value = x1 + x2;
    } else {
        return x3 + x2;
    }
}

function test1(e) {
    const span = document.getElementById('result');
    
    e.value = e.value.replace(/,/gi,'')
    span.innerHTML = Math.floor(e.value / 10);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeyup="test1(this); test2(this.value,this);"/>
<div id='result'></div>
```

change this:

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="onInputChange(this)" onkeyup="separateNum(this.value,this);">
```

to:

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="onInputChange(this); separateNum(this.value,this);">
```

Comment: Thanks @dcr , Cause I do seprated number input 3 number, my secend function have NaN error. Do you have any idea for it?

Comment: once inside your function do a console.log(value) and tell us what you get back

Comment: I updated the snippet to take care of the nan

Answer (score 0):

[**You should not be using inline HTML event attributes in today's world.**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these) Inline event attributes like `onXyz` where how we "wired" up event handling functions to events before we had standards 25+ years ago. Using this technique today "works", but introduces shortcomings and, [in some cases, bigger problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459890/javascript-function-doesnt-work-when-link-is-clicked/43459991#43459991).

Instead, follow modern standards and use [`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) separately in JavaScript, which provides a more robust mechanism for event handling registrations (and [de-registrations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener)). In your case, you would just register two handlers for the same event and they will be invoked in the order that you registered them:

```js
// Get a reference to the HTML element
const input = document.querySelector("input");

// Register event handlers
input.addEventListener("keyup", foo1);
input.addEventListener("keyup", foo2);

function foo1(event){
  console.log("foo1 detected key up after " + event.key + " was pressed and now the input is: " + this.value);
}

function foo2(event){
  console.log("foo2 detected key up after " + event.key + " was pressed and now the input is: " + this.value);
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
```